# Crash when I use getStringArrayListExtra

Tags: java, android

I search to transport a list from an Activity to another Activities using getStringArrayListExtra().
That work perfectly the first time (from MainActivity to Diag2Activity) but the app crash the second time (from Diag2Activity to SstO1Activity).

Each time I use the same methode :
1st Activity :

```
ArrayList<String> BDD = new ArrayList<String>();
BDD.add(tri);

Intent Diag2ActivityIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Diag2Activity.class);
Diag2ActivityIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("BDD", BDD);
startActivity(Diag2ActivityIntent);
```

2nd Activity :

```
Intent i = getIntent();
    ArrayList<String> BDD = i.getStringArrayListExtra("BDD");
```

Can anyone tell me where the error may have come from?
Thanks in advance

Please find the complete code below :

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button mboutonContinuer;
TextView medit_text_gene_1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //appel des différents éléments de l'interface
    mboutonContinuer = findViewById(R.id.boutonContinuer);
    medit_text_gene_1 = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_gene_1);


    //Action quand on clique sur le bouton "continuer" :
    mboutonContinuer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Récupération des valeurs inscrites dans les Edittext
            String tri = medit_text_gene_1.getText().toString();


            //écriture de la Base De Données
            ArrayList<String> BDD = new ArrayList<String>();
            BDD.add(tri);

            //En attendant de pouvoir ajouter un 2ème contact
            BDD.add("rien");

            //Redirection sur la prochaine page
            Intent Diag2ActivityIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Diag2Activity.class);
            Diag2ActivityIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("BDD", BDD);
            startActivity(Diag2ActivityIntent);


        }
    });
}
```

}

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".Controller.MainActivity"
>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Trigramme du diagnostiqueur"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text_gene_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_tech"
            android:hint="XXX"
            android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
            android:maxLength="3"
            android:paddingHorizontal="30dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/boutonContinuer"
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_height="68dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="Continuer ->"
            />


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Diag2Activity.java**

```
public class Diag2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button mboutonContinuer2;
TextView medit_text_sst_1;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_diag2);


    Intent i = getIntent();
    ArrayList<String> BDD = i.getStringArrayListExtra("BDD");

    mboutonContinuer2 = findViewById(R.id.boutonContinuer2);
    medit_text_sst_1 = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_nb_ech);



    mboutonContinuer2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Récupération des valeurs inscrites dans les Edittext
            String brt = medit_text_sst_1.getText().toString();

            //écriture de la base de données
            BDD.add(brt);

            //Redirection vers la prochaine page
            Intent SstO1ActivityIntent = new Intent(Diag2Activity.this, SstO1Activity.class);
            SstO1ActivityIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("BDD", BDD);
            startActivity(SstO1ActivityIntent);

        }
    });
}
```

}

**activity_diag2.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".Controller.Diag2Activity">




<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text_nb_ech"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_ech4"
            android:hint="X"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="2"
            android:paddingHorizontal="30dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/boutonContinuer2"
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_height="68dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:text="Continuer ->" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**SstO1Activity.java**

```
public class SstO1Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button mboutonContinuer3;
Button mboutonech;


Intent i = getIntent();
ArrayList<String> BDD = i.getStringArrayListExtra("BDD");


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sst_o1);

    mboutonContinuer3 = findViewById(R.id.boutonContinuer3);

    mboutonContinuer3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            BDD.add("cc");

            Intent WorkinprogressActivityIntent = new Intent(SstO1Activity.this, WorkinprogressActivity.class);
            startActivity(WorkinprogressActivityIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

**activity_sst_o1.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".Controller.SstO1Activity">



<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Ajouter un commentaire si besoins"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:id="@+id/editText_test1"
            android:background="#DCDCDC"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|text"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:hint="Commentaire..."/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/boutonContinuer3"
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_height="68dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:text="Finir le diagnostic" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Could you share your crash log? And try to initialise the array list in the onCreate of SstO1Activity.java

Comment: Would you mind to surround those the parts where you put and get with a try-catch statement, then share the log of the message of the exception? Example: `try {
    BDD = i.getStringArrayListExtra("BDD");
  } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "getStringExtra exception:" + e.getMessage()); 
  }`

Answer (score 0):

Put below codes to inside `OnCreate` method of `SstO1Activity.java` file.

```
Intent i = getIntent();
ArrayList<String> BDD = i.getStringArrayListExtra("BDD");
```